# How to trigger a custom animation and wait for it to complete before and after data bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am rendering markup which contains wrapping divs every 5 items

```
   <div class="snap" ng-repeat="itemsChunk in items">
        <a class="timeline-item" href="#" ng-repeat="item in casestudyChunk">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="{{item.ImageUrl}}" />
        </a>
   </div>
```

Where item is an array split into chunks. [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Since the markup needs completely re-rendering after the datasource has changed, I can't use the normal animate hooks. I instead want to fade out all the items before the change, and fade the newly rendered markup in.

How can I do this with Angular?

Update

An option I've got is to apply a fadeOut class to the elements, listen for the complete event and then bind afterwards. This doesn't feel like the proper angular way of doing it though. Is there a better way?

Also I am lazy loading images, so need to run a function to trigger this after binding. I have seen this done with a timeout, again if there is a better way I am interested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and add to your

```
<div class="snap" ng-repeat="itemsChunk in items">
```

fadeIn css-class

```
  <div class="snap animated fadeIn" ng-repeat="itemsChunk in items">
```

[there you can find simmilar solution](http://jsbin.com/muvegupu/3/edit)

Comment: I have updated my question a bit. Sure, this is a nice solution for fading the items in. I could also fade out the items in a similar way, but I am wondering if there is a more 'angular' way of doing it